# UIStackView resetting properties of buttons inside it

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uistackview

I'm using the new `UIStackView` to contain 5 buttons.

Each button has a default title that I set in the Storyboard

At `viewDidLoad` I change the `titleLabel.text` property,

I confirmed that the property was being changed by printing the value right after I changed the text, but at `viewDidAppear` the text was back to the default value i set in storyboard.

So i changed it to `viewDidAppear` and began updating all the data there.

Great, until I touch a button. The second i touch a button it resets the `titleLabel.text` property back to the value I set it to in Storyboard.

Is this expected functionality? Is there a way around this?

My current attempt has the text property being set yet again, when i press each button. But for about half a second it blips back to the default value, then back again. REALLY buggy looking

Thanks

**update**: also if I present an alertView it resets the values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `button.titleLabel.text`. Use `button.setTitle("The Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`.

You can set different titles for different states. The button updates its own `titleLabel.text` at various times based on the titles you set with `setTitle:forState:`.